# better rails development server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn, puma, thin, webrick

The rails application I work on makes many 3rd party requests to get data. This often makes the development server slow because those requests takes a while to resolve and they block the other requests.

So far I used WEBrick, thin, puma and unicorn-rails.

WEBrick seems to be good with speed when I benchmarked by firing 20 parallel requests.

Can I do something better so my dev server is non blocking and fast enough?

PS - we use unicorn as production server

Comment: This is very opinion-based but I'd use `puma` and set `RAILS_MAX_THREADS` in `config/puma.rb` to something reasonable/high.

Comment: If you don't need live data from the 3rd party sites you can use the VCR gem to record/cache the requests